# Failed to load settings with 403 on Roblox studio

Tags: roblox, socks

I am on Mac Catalina. Whenever I try to open the Roblox Studio, I get the error message:

[image]

Failed to load settings with 403 on Roblox studio.

There are solutions for Windows OS however, I cannot find any here.

I am connected via a socks proxy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heyo, StackOverflow is a place to get help with programming problems. To get help troubleshooting your installion issues, you should contact Roblox's help desk.

Comment: I did contact them. They could not help me. Thank you.